# How to set flip direction in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The code below is a jquery script that makes the content flip when clicked, everything in this code works fine, but the flip direction flips alternately right to left then left to right, how can I set the direction to make it flip one direction, right to left?

```
var topCard = 1;
var facingUp = true;
var totalFaces = $('#flip-content .contents').length;

function flipCard(n) {

// Replace the contents of the current back-face with the contents
// of the element that should rotate into view.
var curBackFace = $('.' + (facingUp ? 'face2' : 'face1'));
var nextContent = $('#flip-content' + n).html();
var nextContent = $('#flip-content .contents:nth-child(' + n + ')').html();

curBackFace.html(nextContent);

// Rotate the content
$('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
facingUp = !facingUp;

if (topCard === totalFaces) {
    topCard = 0;
}
}

$('#flip-content').on('click', function () {
topCard++;
flipCard(topCard);
});


$(document).ready(function () {
// Add the appropriate content to the initial "front side"
var frontFace = $('.face1');
var frontContent = $('#flip-content .contents:first-child').html();
frontFace.html(frontContent);
});
```

Comment: Am I overlooking it, or is there no flip animation defined in your code snippet? :) All entered code seems valid, but from what I interpret, the card's aren't being flipped visually. One thing though, you are using `var nextContent` twice. Error in the question, or error in your code? :)

Comment: I am guessing you are using `css3` ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your CSS, since it's not posted at the time of my comment, but I believe that you have something backwards. You're telling it to turn that way, so wherever you are using this property, switch it around.

```
.card {
  rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

to

```
.card {
  rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
$('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
```

which will flip your `div` back and forth, you need to add 180 degress on each flip. Something like:

```
var deg=0;
...

deg += 180; 
$('.card').css('transform','rotateY('+deg+'deg)');
```